# Return type of generic function

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to make `getResults` function return the proper type, but currently stuck with this:

```
interface IResponse<T> {
    result: T;
}

type FnType<P, R> = (params: P) => R;

const r1: IResponse<string[]> = { result: ['123'] };
const r2: IResponse<number[]> = { result: [456] };

const getResults = <T, R extends IResponse<T[]>, P>(fn: FnType<P, R>, params: P): T[] => {
    return [
        ...fn(params).result,
        ...fn(params).result
    ];
};

const getValue = <T>(r: IResponse<T>) => r;

// returned type is unknown[]
// how can we make it return string[]?
getResults(getValue, r1);

// returned type is unknown[]
// how can we make it return number[]?
getResults(getValue, r2);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=14&ssc=7&pln=11&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICUIGcAOB7ELCAHgBUA+ZAbwChl7kpsBXAGzAC5lSBuGgXxo0wATxwoAYiFJiSABQA0ydJQC8yABQ44UOAFssXOQEpkqyuj40EBLGEYBGLhmz5CJO1FABzANoBdNWpGFnYuXwByBwAmAGYI-2R+PhtCeyho50xcWxIQZj0AI2gAoKoQrDZOZF8AFgBWADZE5KFUu2RvCDBsqqwzZDIldGQIAA9IEAATfpcc9zJSpTlyDRgQLikZcWJFZXIlbV0DI2MuUgCzSloGELBmKBAauluGADoP9a0dfSxjN6YlXYCher2QHzeXyOv3+gKqoOQ-j4rWstnsXTAADU4KxmCh1GRVlAsq5coTTOZGFYAPTUu4PEAQKbIUTiZDAfrMEAAaxAeAA7iAAjRacgABYC5AIOBPfkoPRwbkoYDpboM5CeHwBAD8NAxvXYWA0GOxuIgSigDmMNLpTHujyZLNk7M5PL5guFool-KlMuQcuQCqV7NV9qe+SKJX8uv1oTARpNOLxFui1qAA)

The code is just an example, in the production `getResults` function is used to merge results from a paginated request (`fn` in this case is a request function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I'm not sure this will also cover the things you need for production. But the return type looks alright like this:

```
interface IResponse<T> {
    result: T;
}

type FnType<P, R> = (params: P) => R;

const r1: IResponse<string[]> = { result: ['123'] };
const r2: IResponse<number[]> = { result: [456] };

const myResults = <P,R>(fn: FnType<P,IResponse<R[]>>, params: P): R[] => {
     return [
        ...fn(params).result,
        ...fn(params).result
    ];
}

const getValue = <T>(r: IResponse<T>) => r;

myResults(getValue, r1);

myResults(getValue, r2);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICUIGcAOB7ELCAHgBUA+ZAbwChl7kpsBXAGzAC5lSBuGgXxo0wATxwoAYiFJiSABQA0ydJQC8yABQ44UOAFssXOQEpkqyuj40EBLGEYBGLhmz5CJO1FABzANoBdNWpGFnYuXwByBwAmAGYI-2R+PhtCeyho50xcWxIQZj0AI2gAoKoQrDZOZF8AFgBWADZE5KFUu2Q9EWyqrDNkYkUVDRgQLikZcUGFFxz3YnRS8iVtXQMjYy5FxPNqOgYQsGYoEBr9g-oAOmvRrR19LGNLpkr2BXOL68vb1Yenl6qH38fEE1ls9m8EDAADU4KxmCh1GRyBooFlXLlkaZdlArO17AAPBz9Lo9dhYDSQmFwhFKKAOYx8AD0TIOAD0APxgwh4VgQS6sPDeDRExltcHIAnREndUJgClU2HwiB06JilnsrntXn8wXCqVioA)

Edit:
I'm actually not exactly sure why the code in question does not give correct IntelliSense, it makes sense to me.

But what I can see is that you used three generic types `T`, `R` and `P`. My Idea is that basically you only have 2 types to worry about which are params and the Result of the method.

I basically say, whatever type is inside the `getValue`'s `IResponse` will be the final output of the `myResults` function.

Comment: The results look good! But it's always best to *explain* an answer, rather than just posting new code. What did you change, and why (other than the obvious: to make it work :-) )?

Comment: Works great, seems I've overthought some parts of typing, thank you! Going to try to understand how it differs now :)

Comment: You are right, I must admint I was basically lazy :D

I Edited the answer and explained my thoughts. But I must also admit that I did not see right away what needs to be done. I played around and "found" the result that way